# Admob ad taking up twice the space in LinearLayout

Tags: android, admob, android-linearlayout

So im running into a issue with my admob ad takeup twice the space within my layout.

I have no idea why its take up this extra space and im looking for someone that can help me out.

[image]

### Layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"  >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/light_grey"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/adlinearlayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/include1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="MY-APP-PUB-ID" >
        </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <include
        android:id="@+id/include2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        layout="@layout/number_pickers" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/include1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/include2"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        layout="@layout/total_weight" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

### Logcat

```
   12-15 02:09:32.265: W/ResourceType(9407): Requesting resource 0x7f0b000d failed because it is complex
   12-15 02:09:32.265: E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(9407): The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
   12-15 02:09:32.335: W/ResourceType(9407): Requesting resource 0x7f0b000d failed because it is complex
   12-15 02:09:32.335: E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(9407): The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
   12-15 02:09:32.345: W/ResourceType(9407): Requesting resource 0x7f0b000d failed because it is complex
   12-15 02:09:32.345: E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(9407): The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
   12-15 02:09:33.597: I/Ads(9407): Scheduling ad refresh 60000 milliseconds from now.
   12-15 02:09:33.597: I/Ads(9407): Ad finished loading.
```

### Code

```
  String id = "ADMOBID";
    adView = new AdView(this);
    adView.setAdUnitId(id);
    adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);

    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.adlinearlayout);

    layout.addView(adView);

    AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder()
    .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)        // All emulators
    .addTestDevice("DEVICE_ID")  // Device
    .build();
    // Load the adView with the ad request.
    adView.loadAd(request);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your settings the height to match_parent. If you go and read the sample on XML it should be set to wrap_content.

Full sample:

```
  <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
                         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         ads:adUnitId="MY_AD_UNIT_ID"
                         ads:adSize="BANNER"/>
```

And here is the [link to official doc](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/fundamentals#play-xml).

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I've changed it to `wrap_content` however still no change. I also attempted to keep the adview within its own layout, then including it as i do with the other content, however it fails everytime, logcat says google play services are not loaded and that the issue is too complex?!?

Comment: @JaisonBrooks if you got something from logcat please share it. Also try to take it out of the LinearLayout

Comment: I have updated the post with Logcat and my actual source code

Comment: @JaisonBrooks you haven't inlcuded google play service library. You need to add the library project google play services (this can be downloaded through the SDK manager)

Comment: This is what im talking about, I have added everything that is need. The ad itself works just fine, However adds this extra space above or below depending on where its located. I've tried it above and below the content. same issue

Comment: @JaisonBrooks well since you get this error I'm pretty sure something must be missing.

Comment: I have resolved the layout issue by removing the Extra linearlayout, what it looks like is that you have to add the AdView within the Parent layout. In my case the Relative layout, i changed my source to reference the Relative, removed the extra linear layout it was within and it seems to display correctly. However the LogCat still logs those same G play services issue

Comment: @JaisonBrooks weird but glad you got it fixed.

Answer (score 2):

You are creating the AdView in both xml and code. 
Choose one, not both.